# How to implement a keyboard listener in a C++ CLI Application

Tags: c++, audio, keyboard, command-line-interface

There are libraries (SFML, SDL, GLFW, etc.) that expose good API for displaying windows and thus handling keyboard events in realtime.

What would you assume to be the most direct way to implement a keyboard listener for a plain command line applications written in C++?

In this particular case, I have written a small program, that patches some oscillators / effects, that produce a stream of data which will be converted to analog audio signals (using the portaudio library). The goal is to react to keyboard hits.

I have heard about JUCE, which seems to be a framework which is capable of creating GUIs and handling GUI events. But it seems just a bit too much for my needs. I just want to create real-time-audio based on keyboard input in a CLI application, and later on there should be MIDI support.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684961(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: what happens, when users click your link?